# Log4J in AS/400

Tags: log4j, ibm-midrange

I am looking for a logging mechanism in AS/400 similar to log4j. I am thinking of writing a wrapper to the log4j in AS/400. Can someone please let me know if there is such a tool present already?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

There are already apenders so I supect the rest should already be done. See here:http://log4j400.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is what you want, but the iSeries performance and system tools can gather a lot of information about your programs. You won't see the source statement, but you do see the calls to the diffent components. These tools are part of the operating system. You just need much autorisation to use them.

Comment: I guess I just want a logging feature for the RPG programs. It'll be easier and better for me to use logs than to manually debug the programs.
Please let me know if there is inbuilt mechanism to do this...

Comment: No, such tools is not available (at least, I've never heard off). But with STRSST you can collect a lot of information that one need for profiling. Also, don't forget to check the joblog. Especially if you manipulate the job- and programattributes you can find a lot of information. 

In other words, nothing like log4j is available. But the iSeries gives much, very much information about the running job. Please, check this out and I would not be surprised if you find what you want.